# How to associate each point (of a large data set) contained in a number of sub-circles to the smallest enclosing circle?

Tags: python, loops, iterator, counter, associative-array

On a 2d plane, there is a large circle centered at (0, 0) with a radius of Ro. It encloses 100 or so smaller circles distributed randomly across the parent circle with unique properties (e.g. radii and positions) each one associated with a unique integer ID. (It is possible that some smaller sub-circles are partially or entirely inside some larger sub-circles.)

The entire plane is gridded uniformly into pixels with sides being horizontal and vertical (along coordinate axes). The size of the pixels is fixed and known a priori but otherwise much smaller than the size of parent circle; there are on the order of few times 10^5  all over the parent circle.

1% of the area of the parent circle is colored in the form of a few clumps across the parent circle covering 10^3 pixels.  These colored pixels are mostly inside sub-circles; all are entirely inside the parent circle. We are given the 2D Cartesian coordinates for (the centers of) all colored grids.

Each colored grid is associated with the smallest sub-circle that contains it.  If the pixel falls within multiple sub-circles, only the smallest of the circles should be chosen.

Finally, I would like to calculate the total number of colored grids associated with each sub-circle subject to the above condition. To write this in python, one should store all of the colored pixels in a 2d array. Then, for each sub-circle, one should query the array to find all grids contained within that sub-circle. For each such grid, one should test whether it is inside the sub-circle. If it is, one should mark that grid as associated with that sub-circle, unless it is already associated with a smaller sub-circle.

Here is my try:

```
totals = {}
sub_circle_catalog = []
for x, y in zip(vals1, vals2):
    enclosing_circles = {}
    for id, position, radius in zip(ids_data, positions_data, radiuss_data): 

        if (np.sqrt(pow(x-position[0], 2)+pow(y-position[1], 2)) < radius):
            enclosing_circles[id] = float('{:.3f}'.format(radius))

            # choose the corresponding ID with the smallest radius here
            smallest_enclosing_circle = min(enclosing_circles, key=enclosing_circles.get)
            sub_circle_catalog.append((enclosing_circles[smallest_enclosing_circle], 1)) 

            # add up all special grids in each sub-circle when looping over all grids
for key, value in sub_circle_catalog:
    totals[key] = totals.get(key, 0) + value
```

I want to know if I am doing the association correctly. I don't know how to implement the constraint that each grid is assigned only once to a sub-circle. In particular, how to loop over all *special* grids in order to calculate total budget of each sub-circle?

Answer (score 0):

After finding all sub-circles containing the *special* colorful grids, one needs to choose the smallest sub-circle. I was doing this incorrectly in the sense that it was done before all sub-circles are looped over. However, my correction here was that I made sure that all sub-circles are looped over for any single *special* grid and just before moving to the next *special* grid in the row, I need to assert a line that takes care of the smallest local sub-circle and store it into some list. As each *special* grid is taken care of this way, all the smallest sub-circles are added to the empty list (initialized at the beginning). Once all *special* grids are investigated this way, we can add the sum of the individual contributions to the empty dictionary (initialized at the beginning). All this is being done in the same scope as that of the first `for` statement. Here is the correct code:

```
totals = {}
sub_circle_catalog = []

for x, y in zip(vals1, vals2):
    enclosing_circles = {}

    for id, position, radius in zip(ids_data, positions_data, radiuss_data): 

        if (np.sqrt(pow(x-position[0], 2)+pow(y-position[1], 2)) < radius):
            enclosing_circles[id] = float('{:.4f}'.format(radius))

    # choose the corresponding ID with the smallest radius here
    if enclosing_circles != {}:
        smallest_enclosing_circle = min(enclosing_circles, key=enclosing_circles.get)
        sub_circle_catalog.append((enclosing_circles[smallest_enclosing_circle], 1)) 

# add up all special grids in each sub-circle when looping over all grids
for key, value in sub_circle_catalog:
    totals[key] = totals.get(key, 0) + value

    totals = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(totals.items()))
    totals = list(totals.items())
    with open('/the/path/to/the/file.txt', "a") as my_file:
        print('{}'.format(totals), file=my_file)
        my_file.close()
```